# Receber valor da variável sem passar por parâmetro

Tags: c#, .net, string, método, extension-method

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private string toCamelCase(string text)
{
    text = string.Format("{0}{1}",text.Substring(0, 1).ToLower(),text.Substring(1));
    return text;
}
```

Para utilizá-lo preciso chamar assim:

```
toCamelCase("OlaMundo");
```

Quero que funcione assim:

```
"OlaMundo".toCamelCase
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O que você quer chama-se [método de extensão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Veja o [artigo na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method). E [artigo na MSDN Magazine me português](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/november/basic-instincts-extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (está em VB.NET mas é a mesma coisa).

Ele precisa seguir algumas regras:

- Precisa estar no mesmo mesmo `namespace` do tipo que você está usando como primeiro parâmetro (sim, é um parâmetro, mesmo que ele aparece fora dos parênteses do método, sempre é assim em qualquer método). Não é bem que precise, mas faz mais sentido assim se para ajudar as ferramentas como Intellisense funcionarem melhor. De fato se você quiser usar este método apenas em circunstâncias específicas então é melhor usar outro nome. Mas o mais comum é usar o mesmo nome do tipo original para que este método esteja sempre disponível quando o tipo é usado.
- Precisa estar em uma classe estática além do método ser estático também. A classe pode ter qualquer nome. É comum os programadores colocarem o sufixo `Extension` ou `Ext` para indicar que é uma classe que contém métodos de extensão. Pode colocar qualquer método estático lá dentro mas o ideal é só colocar métodos de extensão que estejam relacionados entre si.
- Precisa ter o modificador `this` antes do primeiro parâmetro que será usado com objeto a ser trabalhado. Ele é que realmente determinada que a sintaxe de objeto em primeiro lugar possa ser usada.
- Evite usar tipos do primeiro parâmetro que possam gerar hierarquias. Por exemplo evite muito usar `object`, principalmente se estiver no `Namespace System`. Se fizer isto qualquer tipo de dado passará contar com seu método como se fosse nativo. Isso poluirá a tabela de *lookup* de métodos e fará ferramentas como Intellisense não serem tão úteis.
- Cuidado para não confundir com um método já existente no tipo. O compilador tem suas regras para decidir qual usar mas pode não ficar tão claro para o programador e criar *bugs* demorados para se perceber.
- Prefira estender tipos que você não tem controle. Se você pode adicionar um método dentro do tipo, faça-o! Por isto faz bem pouco sentido que ele seja `private`. Nem sei se funciona (acho que sim).

Exemplo:

```
namespace System {
    public static StringExt {
        public static string ToCamelCase(this string text) {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", text.Substring(0, 1).ToLower(), text.Substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Qx42No). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xo7KMb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ExtensionExample.cs).

Na chamada os parênteses ainda são necessários.

```
"OlaMundo".toCamelCase();
```

Answer (score 4):

Defina um método de extensão (Extension Method) à classe string:

```
public static string toCamelCase(this string text)
{
    text = string.Format("{0}{1}",text.Substring(0, 1).ToLower(),text.Substring(1));
    return text;
}
```