# Para que serve o System.Linq no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-method

Fiz essa pergunta aqui no SOPT

[Qual é o equivalente ao array_map do PHP em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125595/qual-%C3%A9-o-equivalente-ao-array-map-do-php-em-c#125596)

E fiquei curioso para saber do que se trata esse `System.Linq`.

Pois quando eu tentei usar o código da resposta acima sem usar ele, obtive um erro:

```
 var arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3}.Select(x => x * 2).ToArray();
```

> Compilation error (line 8, col 33): 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

No caso, `int[]` por padrão não tem o método `Select`?

O que seria esse `System.Linq`? Por que tenho que importar esse *namespace* para que a função `Select`  funcione nesse `array`simples?

**Nota**: Venho do PHP, onde, para manipular `array`, você tem que usar funções. Então desculpem se pareço ser ignorante em C#.

Comment: Veja se preciso responder algo mais, ou preciso melhorar pra esclarecer mais.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isso especificamente é um [*namespace* do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101). Veja em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15666/101). Assim como no PHP, se algo está dentro de um *namespace* precisa ser "importado" para ter acesso aos seus membros (a não ser que use o nome completo).

Obviamente que [a biblioteca que contém esses tipos precisa estar referenciada no projeto também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40761/101), mas isso é outro problema fora da linguagem em si.

O método `Select()` é um algoritmo genérico para manipular qualquer tipo que seja um [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) (tem [pergunta sobre esta interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101)). Tem [vários algoritmos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) assim. Isso faz parte da linguagem de consultas à [coleções de dados enumeráveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101), o chamado [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

A [documentação mostra as interfaces implementadas pelo tipo `Array`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) (cuidado porque a classe *linkada* aqui é apenas uma utilitária para o tipo que é nativo na linguagem e não representa o tipo propriamente dito, como costuma acontecer nos demais tipos).

Os métodos que estão nesse *namespace* específico são [métodos de extensão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (especificamente na classe estática [`Enumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3) ([veja o fonte dela](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3)) e [no .NET Core ficou mais organizado](https://source.dot.net/#q=enumerable)), então eles aparentam ser do próprio tipo, mas são externos, por isso precisam ser explicitamente referenciados - através do *namespace* - quando deseja usá-los.

Poderiam ser funções normais (métodos estáticos normais), mas perderia a [uniformidade da sintaxe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) e a facilidade de descobrir o que está disponível para o tipo quando for usar um mecanismo de auto-completação de um IDE.

Uso do método de extensão:

```
objeto.Metodo()
```

Uso do método estático normal:

```
Classe.Metodo(objeto)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KfAaeV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KkEar7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ExtensionExample2.cs).

Não vou entrar em [detalhes sobre os métodos de extensão porque já tem uma pergunta específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41944/101) sobe isso e não precisamos repetir aqui.

Tem uma técnica não muito recomendada para não precisar fazer isso nos seus métodos de extensão: cria a classe que conterá esses métodos dentro do *namespace* que normalmente terá os tipos que eles estendem. Por exemplo, se colocar os seus métodos no `namespace System`, então é provável que eles sempre estejam disponíveis. Mas corre-se o risco de ter colisões de nomes gratuitamente.

Ver mais sobre o [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

[Exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153264/101).

Comment: Interessante esse último exemplo sobre a extensão de métodos... Fiz um fiddle e funcionou certinho https://dotnetfiddle.net/DYZDrl

Comment: Coloquei o código fonte dos métodos da `Enumerable` do `System.Linq`. É, funciona com as duas sintaxes, desde que coloque o `this`, sem ele só funciona como função normal.

Answer (score 13):

[`System.Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx) é o *namespace* que implementa a Language Integrated Query (LINQ), ou seja, a sintaxe do C# para iterar seletivamente sobre coleções.

> No caso, `int[]` por padrão não tem o método `Select`?

Não. `Select` neste caso é um método de extensão implementado em `System.Linq`, e que só aparece quando se faz menção ao *namespace*.

> Por que tenho que importar esse *namespace* para que a função `Select` funcione nesse *array* simples?

No C#, podemos implementar métodos de extensão, que são métodos implementados fora da classe original, mas que atuam juntamente com a classe original, estendendo esta classe.

Por exemplo:

```
public static class MinhasExtensions
{
    public static int[] MeuMetodo(this int[] meuarray) // O operador this diz que é uma extensão a qualquer objeto do tipo int[].
    {
        return meuarray.Select(x => x * 2).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Então posso usar assim:

```
var arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var outro_arr = arr.MeuMetodo(); // Isso faz a mesma coisa que o respondido na pergunta-exemplo.
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ypKPeX).

Answer (score 2):

Nada mais é do que métodos de extensão para seu objeto.
Você precisa saber que: 
Usando linq suas coleções (Array, ArrayList, SortedList e etc..) ganharão mais métodos para iteração como Select OrderBy FirstOrDefault, LastOrDefault, Sort, Find e muitos outros que vão lhe atender em praticamente todos os casos que você necessitar sem a necessidade de "reinventar a roda".

Lembre-se que a documentação do próprio .net framework é sempre um ótimo lugar para se ter uma ideas dos métodos e atributos que sua classe/objeto possuí.

Segue um exemplo da documentação de linq:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx

Bons estudos.