# URI 1259 - Pares crescentes e ímpares decrescentes

Tags: c#, array, .net, algoritmo

Estou resolvendo [esse](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1259) desafio do URI Online Judge.

Porém o meu código tem tido a resposta "Time limit exceeded", e não entendi exatamente o porquê.

Segue código abaixo:

```
 using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace URI_1259
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int i;
            int[] arr = new int[numero];
            int[] numeroParCrescente = new int[numero];
            int[] numeroImparDecrescente = new int[numero];


            for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                numeroParCrescente = arr.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                numeroImparDecrescente = arr.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
            }

            foreach(var item in numeroParCrescente)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            foreach(var item in numeroImparDecrescente)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Qual o motivo, ou alguma forma de otimizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faz sentido classificar e transformar em *array* toda vez que pegar um dado. Precisa entender o que está usando, o que acontece com cada parte do código, os custos disso, como opera. Não use nada sem entender completamente como funciona, caso contrário não estará aprendendo programar, está só chutando algo para ver o resultado.

Então apenas peça todos os dados em, um laço e depois faço só dois laços que imprima já filtrando e classificando como pede durante a impressão, sem fazer conversão alguma.

Se não for o suficiente terá que abandonar o LINQ e fazer um único *loop* para separar e classificar os dados.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;
 
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
            int numero = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[numero];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            foreach(var item in arr.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).OrderBy(x => x)) WriteLine(item);
            foreach(var item in arr.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).OrderByDescending(x => x)) WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/umckKz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DnZgTI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FilterAndSort.cs).

Eu não fiz a verificação da validade da entrada de dados porque é só um exercício que será testado de forma automática e a entrada será correta, mas se um humano fosse digitar e entrasse com algo inválido a aplicação quebraria. Então tenha em mente que não é assim que se faz aplicação real, foi feito assim porque é para passar no URI.

Veja mais em:

- [O que é tecnologia LINQ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101)
- [Para que serve o System.Linq no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101)