# Como funcionam os parâmetros que os métodos do LINQ recebem?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda, parâmetros

Como funcionam os parâmetros dentro desses métodos que recebem esse esses parâmetros:

```
<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

[image: Assinatura]

Um exemplo é o método `Where`, eu sei que ele recebe uma *expressão lambda*.

Existe alguma uma forma de criar um método com esses parâmetros para simular e entender o que são esses: `TSource`, `Func`, `bool`, `predicate` e entender o que acontece quando eu passo, por exemplo : `p => p.Nome == "Mauricio"` para o método?

O que eu tenho que estudar para entender isso?

[image: Intelissense]

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem o que quer, o texto está um pouco confuso. Quer ver o fonte do `Where`?

Comment: Acho que se eu visse o fonte do Where ia me ajudar a entender como isso funciona.

Comment: Eu quero entender como esse parâmetro funciona, eu acho muito confuso de entender o que ele espera, diferente de entender isso (int i) onde o método seria: public void recebeInteiro(int i)

Comment: Você quer saber como ele funciona em memória? Ou num contexto de banco de dados, como por exemplo usando Linq to Entities ou Entity Framework?

Comment: Sabe quando a gente abre o "Lista.Where(" e ele mostra o parâmetro que espera receber? Então eu sei que ele recebe uma lambda mas sei pq decorrei e não por que sei ler aquele parâmetro, queria entender o que ele faz com a lambda internamente, não sei se ficou claro :(

Comment: @MauricioFerraz a pergunta e os comentários ainda não deixam tão claro o que deseja. Não é o ideal ir fazendo interativamente, mas para tentar te atender, veja as respostas postas, indique se é isso que deseja, se é algo um pouco diferente, se falta algo que é importe. Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar toda informação possível e deixar a pergunta mais clara. Cuidado para não invalidar as respostas existentes.

Comment: @bigown obrigado, era isso mesmo o que eu queria, já estudei os métodos de extensão e agora to nos delegates e func. Abraço.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tem o [código fonte dele disponível](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). No mesmo arquivo tem todo código do LINQ. Todo o código do .NET pode ser visto e facilmente nesse site. [No .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,b7b87afe6c3fc715) está dividido em vários arquivos.

Há uma pergunta que fala sobre alguns detalhes: [Para que serve o System.Linq no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101)

Acho que também será útil: [Diferenças entre forma declarativa e imperativa do LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

Também: [Como funciona a lógica do Where no Entity Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101).

## *Generics*

Esse `TSource` é uma espécie de super variável. Ele é substituído por um tipo específico que será usado naquela estrutura de dados. Isso é chamado de [programação genérica. É algo importante estudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101).

## `Func<>`

Isso é um método delegado com uma assinatura específica para poder receber o código que será usado como filtro. Toda vez que um método será passado é preciso indicar a assinatura dele. [Estude outra pergunta sobre o `Func<>` para entender melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90058/101). O `predicate` aí é só o nome do argumento. O `TSource` é o tipo que está na coleção de dados a ser avaliada (note que no *screenshot* foi usado `Despesa` no lugar de `TSource`. O `bool` é o tipo de retorno desse método, afinal esse método sempre tem que responder se a condição atendeu ou não.

## `IEnumerable`

Esses métodos só podem ser executados em objetos que possuem a implementação da [interface `IEnumerable`. Estude ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101). Esses objetos certamente terão associados um objeto iterador para ir passo a passo em cada elemento do objeto.

## `Yield`

Os algoritmos obviamente são diferentes mas a estrutura básica de todos é ter um laço percorrendo o objeto que está sendo processado (ele tem que ser um enumerável) e após algum processamento (possivelmente uma verificação de filtro) é retornado um elemento ou algum outro resultado.

Se retornar um elemento é feito com `yield` assim ele encerra o algoritmo para aquele elemento e quando voltar nele o algoritmo continuará do próximo elemento. Para entender melhor como isso funciona [deve estudar o `yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101).

## Métodos de extensão

Note que esses métodos dão a ilusão deles pertenceram ao objeto, mesmo não sendo. Eles são [*extension methods*. Esse é outro ponto a estudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41944/101). Ele usa o `this` visto ali no primeiro parâmetro para indicar que o método pode ser executado como parte do objeto, mas no fundo apenas está passando um objeto para o método (nada diferente dos métodos normais, só que neles isso fica "escondido" do programador, em método de extensão isso é explícito).

## *Lambda*

Normalmente o que é passado como [argumento (e não parâmetro)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para esses métodos são [*lambdas* (estude isso)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Elas são funções anônimas ([se conhece JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101)). É uma forma de criar uma referência para uma função (a groso modo). Essa referência pode ser guardada em uma variável ou passada como argumento. Quem receber essa referência vai chamar essa função.

Então pode-se entender que está passando uma função como argumento. É uma forma de dar um corpo para a iteração desse objeto enumerável.

Quando passa a função em vez de executar o código e passar o resultado, você passa o código para ser executado lá dentro da função que o receberá.

[Como ler expressões *lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22265/101).

Pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99382/101

## Exemplos

Em resumo simplificado ele faz:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (T element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) { //está chamando o código que executará a condição
            yield return element;
        }
    }
```

Note que essa *lambda* tem a assinatura obrigatória de receber um enumerável de um tipo específico e retornará um `bool`, afinal o resultado será usado em um `if`, tem que ser um booleano para tomar a decisão. Como consumidor deve saber que aquela expressão deve ser uma condição.

Reforço que esse método será chamado uma vez, processará um único elemento e encerrará. Por causa do `yield` ele mantém o estado. Então quando entrar a próxima vez ele não executará mais naquele elemento, ele irá para o próximo da coleção enumerável. Vai assim até ser encerrado por alguma forma (pode ser que tenha passado por todos os elementos).

Como ele retorna um elemento por vez para manter o controle disso é preciso retornar o próprio enumerador para manter o controle e poder passar o elemento para outros métodos do LINQ, mais ou menos como se faz com [interface fluente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101).

O `Any()` não usa o `yield`, ele não retorna elementos um por um, retorna se achou ou não:

```
public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (T element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Já o `Count()` retorna um inteiro com a contagem, então ele tem que ir acumulando:

```
public static int Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    int count = 0;
    foreach (T element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Lambda.cs).

[Mais exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116099/101).

## Conclusão

Você pode criar outros métodos que complementem o LINQ. Basta seguir esse padrão (leia como criar um método de extensão no *link* da seção acima sobre o assunto). Sempre vai ter um laço, terá que chamar *lambda* passada, quase sempre dentro de um `if`, mas não necessariamente e terá que retornar um resultado final ou um elemento através de um gerador (`yield`). Eles não são mágicos, especiais, coisa da linguagem. Foram feitos para que qualquer programador com conhecimento necessário possa fazer o que precisa sem maiores complicações e dar melhor abstração para seus algoritmos.

Aconselho pesquisar sobre esses termos que passei na resposta aqui mesmo no SOpt e aprender mais sobre eles. Dei apenas os *links* básicos. O que não encontrar pode ir perguntando individualmente.

Comment: Eu acho que é exatamente isso o que eu queria saber, o problema é que eu sei tão pouco sobre o assunto que ficou difícil de fazer uma pergunta clara rsrs. Vou estudar em cima de sua resposta para depois aprovar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Funcionamento dos parâmetros, você encontra na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) da Microsoft.

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
>   this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
>   Func<TSource, bool> predicate
> )
> ```
>
> Parâmetros:
>
> - source: IEnumerable a filtragem.
> - predicate: Uma função para testar cada elemento para uma condição.
>
> Valor de retorno:
>
> - Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> - IEnumerable que contém os elementos da sequência de entrada que satisfazem a condição.
>
> Parâmetros de tipo:
>
> - TSource: O tipo dos elementos de source.

Exemplo:

```
List<string> fruits =
    new List<string> { "apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                    "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry" };

IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);

foreach (string fruit in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

A implementação você encontra no  site [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) ou [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Yq096YnR).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu não sabia que existia esse "referencesource" eu achava que era bloqueado para consulta. Isso vai me ajudar muito Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como consultar esse referencesource para o EntityFramework?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz, não sei se é isso que você quer, olha ai no git: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework